# update query not updating in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql, pg

Not updating postgresql database when update_all using

```
@change_stat = Notification.where("fb_id = ? AND active = ?",@current_user.fb_id,true)
@change_stat.update_all(:active => false)
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, but i could see that update set active = false, but not reflect in postgresql databse

Comment: what type of column is active? is it a boolean or string?

Comment: if active is not set as attr_accessible in your model this will not update. You need to call .save separetely

Comment: That's not a query. Please show the SQL, and the exact error if any. Enable logging in RAils or set `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf`.